# Private messages with Faye and Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, messaging, faye, railscasts

I'm using the [faye gem](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) menitioned in [the railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) allowing apps to push messages. Problem is it pushes messages to all chat clients that are open. I need them to be private. It's possible to get private messaging with faye but it's url based. For example all messages will be sent to `site.com/foo`. But, in my model the chat doesn't have a specific url. Because chat is just a collection of messages sent to you by that user.

So if you're logged in as adam  `site.com/messages/eve` would allow you to talk to eve but for eve it's the reverse.  `site.com/messages/adam`. So URL specific private chat is seemingly out of the question.

Any pointers?

*messages_controller.rb* ( triggering ajax )

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(message_params)
  @message.save
end
```

*create.js.erb* ( calling a broadcast method )

```
<% broadcast params[:message][:username] do %>
  $(".text-wrap").append("<%= current_user.name %> <%= @message.body %></div>");
<% end %>
```

*broadcast method* ( posting to the faye server )

```
def broadcast(user, &block)
  channel = "/messages/#{user}"
  message = {:channel => channel, :data => capture(&block)}
  uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:9292/faye")
  Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, :message => message.to_json)
end
```

*application.js* ( faye server subscription to /messages/* )

```
$(function(){
    var faye = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');
    var subscription = faye.subscribe('/messages/*', function(message) {
        eval(message);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it! The problem was that I had the subscribe function in application.js meaning it would run the subscribe javascript on each page. Instead what I did is at the bottom of the chat page view i subscribed to `/messages/eve/adam`. This is how I did that:

```
<script>  
  $(function(){
    var faye = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');
    var subscription = faye.subscribe('/messages/#{current_user.username}/#{@user.username}', function(message) {
      eval(message);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Then in the broadcast method I made sure to send the information to only the correct place.

```
def broadcast(user, &block)
  channel = "/messages/#{current_user.username}/#{user}"
  message = {:channel => channel, :data => capture(&block)}
  uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:9292/faye")
  Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, :message => message.to_json)
end
```